# restriction of web service by ip

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security

I have a web service that will provide data to another web application. My problem is deriving from security concern. I don't want the web service to work if the IP of machine that the service is working on is different from the ip I want. For example If somebody copies the web service to his pc, it should not work because the ip address have changed. Moroveri mac address can also be an alternative for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying a web service is not possible unless you have the source code or the binaries.
If the web service provides data to another web app, simply put a firewall rule that blocks connections from any other IP different from the one you want.

Comment: If you have access to the binaries, you might as well decompile it. The whole security issue from certain IP addresses should be handled at the network layer, not the app.

Comment: The program is open source. I know the restrictions by network settings but I have no authentication to control the network.

Comment: If you don't control the network at least you control the data since you say you are the provider of the data. Where is the data coming from? Is it a database? If so, what kind of database (MySQL, SQL Server)?

Comment: @gipsydipsydoo - if its **open source** then *anyone* can run the same application on *their* machines and provide services that *they* want. Your question is confusing - you seem to want to simply lock down **your version of the same application**, because you presumably provide something unique than anyone else using the same **open source library**.

Comment: I have an application that will work on different machines and I don't have exe or dll to run application. Because it's platform is javascript comunicating with a webservice I have to give the source of the file. I am controlling security on database (mssql). However, I want to increase the security by preventing the source code from runnin on any pc. My customers are simple users and I think they cannot overcome the ip change process.

Comment: However, they are , of course , able to copy and paste the project. There fore I am ONLY and ONLY asking for IP restriction of a web service. Is it undertandable enough? I began to think that stackoverflow users are unable to understand English. Please read the question before answering. I know alternative methods to increase security. I am asking for this method. Do not advice please. If you know an answer say it.

Answer (score -1):

If you were to restrict access by  IP address, you would need to change your security configuration every time the IP address changes. For instance, if a second network adapter is added to the server, or if the server is moved to a different network segment.

Also, how will you debug the web service on different machines? Or how would you have a QA environment, which will naturally have a different IP address than in the production environment?